# ASP.NET/IIS <---> Solr/Tomcat setup on EC2 - "best practice" configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, tomcat, solr

I am an ec2 newbie and deploying an asp.net application that interfaces with Apache solr (on Tomcat). In my dev environment I am running ASP.NET and Solr/Tomcat on my windows box.

1. I am also thinking of using a single c3.2xlarge instance to run all of them together on the same instance (mirroring my dev setup). Do you see any issue?
2. Alternately, is it advisable to move Solr to a separate instance? and running ASP.NET/IIS on a windows instance. Is there a best practice for such a setup? i.e. how much memory/storage and what kind of ec2 instance to use?

I am confused on the trade-offs if any, and also the cost implications. Could anyone share their insights? Thanks in advance for helping a newbie out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a pre-configured Solr instance from Amazon marketplace.

See https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B008ASKV8U

I have used this on Linux along with IIS on Windows successfully.